# Visual C++17 Error C2280 attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, unique-ptr

I'm trying to port a Bencode library originally I wrote in C# to C++.

Abstract Base class

```
class BObjectBase
{
    protected:
        BObjectBase() = default;

    public:         
        virtual std::shared_ptr<BObjectBase> GetParent() = 0;           
};
```

Abstract Derived template class

```
template<typename T>
class BObjectValue : public BObjectBase
{
    protected:
        BObjectValue() = default;

    public:
        virtual T GetValue() = 0;
};
```

Generic Derived class

```
template<typename T>
class BObject : public BObjectValue<T>
{
    private:
        const std::shared_ptr<BObjectBase> parent;
        const T value;

    protected:
        BObject(const std::shared_ptr<BObjectBase> p, const T v) : parent(p), value(v)
        {

        }

    public:
        std::shared_ptr<BObjectBase> GetParent()
        {
            return parent;
        }
        T GetValue()
        {
            return value;
        }
};
```

Class to represent Bencoded Integer

```
class BInteger : public BObject<long>
{
    public:
        BInteger(
            const std::shared_ptr<BObjectBase> parent,
            const long value)
                : BObject<long>(parent, value)
        {

        }
};
```

Class to represent Bencoded String

```
class BString : public BObject<std::vector<std::byte>>
{
    public:
        BString(
            const std::shared_ptr<BObjectBase> parent,
            const std::vector<std::byte> value)
                : BObject<std::vector<std::byte>>(parent, value)
        {

        }
};
```

Class to represent Bencoded List

```
class BList : public BObject<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BObjectBase>>>
{
    public:
        BList(
            const std::shared_ptr<BObjectBase> parent,
            const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BObjectBase>> value)
                : BObject<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BObjectBase>>>(parent, value)
        {
            
        }
};
```

Both class BInteger & BString compiles but BList fails.
Double clicking on the error leads to xmemory file.

When I switch from unique_ptr to raw it complies, which I'm trying to avoid.

I'm stuck on this since morning. I'm fairly new to C++. The idea is to rewrite the whole thing in C++ to learn C++.

Compiler - Microsoft VC++ set to C++17 on VS2019

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2280   'std::unique_ptr<BObjectBase,std::default_delete>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<BObjectBase,std::default_delete> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function  Bencode C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\xmemory 694

Comment: Please provide full compiler error you get.

Comment: Please try to create a single cohesive [mcve] to show us. And then copy-paste the full and complete build output from that example, and add comments on the lines where you get the errors.

Comment: Attempting to rewrite a program in another language into C++ is not the most efficient way to learn C++. Attempting to rewrite a program in another language, line by line, into C++, will only end in tears. C++ is not Java, and C++ is not C#. C++ works in fundamentally different ways. One needs to understand what another program is trying to do, then reimplement it in C++, using C++ concepts and programming techniques that one learns after spending several years learning C++.

Comment: This is very suspicious: `BList(const std::shared_ptr<BObjectBase> parent, const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BObjectBase>> value): BObject<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BObjectBase>>>(parent, value)` Providing a vector by value for initialization of a member var. forces the compiler to make a copy but this isn't permitted for `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I agree. It is not line by line rewrite.

Comment: @AlexDavid: "*It is not line by line rewrite.*" And yet your code shows all of the hallmarks of that. The use of a unified base class that even basic integer values must inherit from being the most obvious example. An overabundance of shared pointers without clear ownership relationships between types being another example. You may not have done it literally "line by line", but what you've written isn't C++ code. It's C# mascaraing as C++.

Comment: @AlexDavid: Overall, it's unclear how to answer this question because it's unclear what you mean for your code to actually accomplish. That is, what all of these objects are supposed to mean, how they relate to each other, why `BObject` takes a pointer to some parent object, why `BObject`'s `value` member is `const`, etc. Indeed, your over use of `const` is why your code doesn't compile, but it's not clear what the purpose of any of this is.

Comment: @NicolBolas "Indeed, your over use of const is why your code doesn't compile". I tried removing all const and yet fails to compile. Your comments are not helping.